# How to submit tax forms in marketplace?

Tags: magento2, marketplace

i get a notification submit your tax forms and then resubmit the extension to Marketing Review.But i don't know how do it? I need help to everyone!

Comment: Hello Xanka, have you find the way to submit tax forms?

Comment: yes i was received email form marketplace teams. Please inbox me your email, i will send it to you or you can contact magento marketplace teams if you need more informations.

Comment: Thanks Xanka, my email is nalin.j.savaliya@gmail.com Please send me email

Comment: i was sent from nalin.j.savaliya@gmail.com. Good luck!

Comment: You will get email from marketplace with tax forms to submit, no automation process for that on Magento marketplace as for end of 2017

Comment: Hi Xanka, To submit do we need to fill form and then scan copy need to mail to marketplace@magento.com ?

Comment: Refer This Answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208425/35758