# "Missing Tax Forms" while submitting Magento extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace, submission

I have submitted two of my extensions to magento marketplace. It passed

1. Technical
2. QA Review

But I got stuck in a "Marketing issue" it says "**Missing Tax Forms**"

I had done research and finally find out I have to submit a form **W-8BEN** as I am from India & an individual developer.

Now I couldn't find a link in magento where I can submit this form.

I have two question

1. Do I need to fill and prepare a scan copy of this form?
2. To submit form is there any link or i need to send mail to marketplace@magento.com ?

I found one question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167305/how-to-submit-tax-forms-in-marketplace) relevant to me but it has no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I got the same message when I upload my first extension on the marketplace.

You can simply fill the form by online pdf editor and send it to **marketplace@magento.com** with **subject: Tax Information for Magento Marketplace.**

After 2 days I got this mail from Marketplace. And then my module will pass Marketing Review.

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Magento Marketplace Support.  The Marketplace
>   team has received the tax forms and filed in our system. There is no
>   further action required at the current time by your team regarding
>   this issue.
>
> Thank you,
>
> Marketplace Support
>
> marketplace@magento.com

**These are the rules for form**

**United States Resident**

- Please complete a W-9 Form and scan the completed form and return to Magento
- Magento will prepare and file a 1099-K with IRS and will send you a copy

**International Resident**

**1. Are you are currently paying taxes in the U.S.?**

- If yes, you can either:

  - Complete a W-8ECI form (return completed form to Magento) and Magento will not need to withhold on your behalf
  - Not complete a W-8ECI form, and Magento will need to withhold up to 30% (depending on your country of residence) of the 70% revenue share from the developer and remit to IRS
- If no:

  - and the country where you are located DOES have a tax treaty (https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/united-states-income-tax-treaties-a-to-z) with the U.S. government, have you completed a W-8BEN (individual developer) or W-8BEN-E (business developer) Form?

    - If yes, return completed W-8BEN (individual developer) or W-8BEN-E (business developer) form to Magento and Magento will withhold a percentage in accordance with IRS per your country of residence
    - If no, Magento needs to withhold the maximum of 30% of the 70% revenue share from the developer and remit to IRS
  - nd the country where you are located DOES NOT have a tax treaty with the U.S government, Magento needs to withhold the maximum of 30% of the 70% revenue share from the developer and remit to IRS

    2. Magento will prepare and file a 1042-S with IRS and will send you a copy

**Best Of Luck.**

Comment: Can i found detail about Tax forms in my magento marketplace account ?

Answer (score 0):

My two extensions are live in Marketplace now :)

1. [Easy Frontend HTML Dynamic Sitemap](https://marketplace.magento.com/akhilg-module-sitemap.html)
2. [Easy Product Reviews Import Export](https://marketplace.magento.com/akhilg-module-review.html)

Here is **one liner solution** for my question

What I have to do is fill [W-8BEN](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf) form (For Individual developer) and send an scan copy to marketplace@magento.com.

Next working day I received mail from Marketplace team as they received my tax form and I am good to go. Hope will help someone.